# ng is not recognised as an internal or external command. Jenkins + Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, jenkins, angular-cli, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to setup Jenkins for an Angular CLI project. I have installed node and Angular Cli on the Jenkins server under a specific user account.
if I open a command prompt on the server an execute the following commands to verify they are installed properly, this is the result:

[image]

I have configured the project with Jenkins, and i created two build steps two execute two bat files.

One runs: npm install

and the second one runs: ng build --prod

Then I build Jenkins, it runs the npm install but it fails running ng build --prod because it says " 'ng' is not recognised as an internal or external command".

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to probably use the angular cli on the node_modules folder, So it does not need to use the angular cli installed on the server. It seems like Angular CLI is installed only for my user on the server but not for the user Jenkins use to build.

PS: I installed Angular CLI globally using:

npm i -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to install angular cli on server, just run

```
npm run ng -- build
```

That will run the local version from your project `devDependencies`

This way you can pass any flag to your local cli `npm run ng -- test`, `npm run ng -- lint`, etc

> You can pass additional flags to `ng` just like that
>   `run ng -- build --prod`

More details at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: This is working but its excluding the additional parameters like --test when running the build

Comment: For everyone who is still finding this post via search, you can check my answer to the question to see how to include additional parameters like --test when running the build (in short, use: npm run ng -- build --test)

Answer (score 9):

Just for further clarification when someone searches for the same problem and finds this question (as I did):

If you want to use the --prod flag while running the build command, as asked in this question, you can use:

```
npm run ng -- build --prod
```

Important are the "--" between "ng" and "build" with spacing. This is due to the syntax of "npm run", more information can be found here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

This also solves the problem described in a comment below the accepted answer: *"This is working but its excluding the additional parameters like --test when running the build"*

Answer (score 2):

```
npm run ng -- build
```

we can use as this without installing angular cli

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on the Local command prompt, Restart the Jenkin server.

Restart Jenkins --> http://host-name:port/base-url/restart

```
                ex:- http://localhost:8080/jenkins/restart
```

If it is not working on local command as well install angular CLI globally and set the environment settings and do the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

try as below.

## BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup ng serve

Answer (score -1):

The only issue with `npm run ng build` is it omits any other parameter like `--prod` or `--test` after build.

Following are the commands what i am using to run my angular build successfully from Jenkins.The last command is executed the dirty way by setting up the path variables. Don't know if there is a cleaner way to do this. This does execute the commands properly without omitting anything.

```
@echo on
cmd /c npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

echo yarn Install
cmd /c yarn

echo Build
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;
ng build --prod --aot=true
```